# Ansible: How to determine if a specified host is listed in a list of string arrays?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to create a vault (`1password`, not Ansible vaults) for each host in the inventory.

```yaml
- name: Get the vault list
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: op vaults list
  register: vaults_list
```

This returns

```yaml
 stdout: |-
    ID                            NAME
    3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
    feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
    6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault
```

Which I can convert to a list of arrays with this

```yaml
- name: Parse the list
  ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
    my_vault_list: "{{ vaults_list.stdout_lines | map('split') | to_yaml }}"
```

producing

```yaml
 my_vault_list: |-
    - [ID, NAME]
    - [3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy, rpi-tick1-keyvault]
    - [feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m, rpi-tick2-keyvault]
    - [6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa, rpi-tick3-keyvault]
```

but what I haven't been able to figure out is,

**How to run a play that determines whether a specific hostname (such as `rpi-tick4`) is in the keyvault list?**

Thanks for any help.

Thanks to @U880D for a very complete answer!  I did have one question though.

I now have the following to detect if the vault exists. It looks like this...

```yaml
- name: Does list_of_vaults contain the host_vault_name?
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that: host_vault_name in list_of_vaults
    success_msg: "Vault {{ host_vault_name }} found at index: {{ lookup('ansible.utils.index_of', list_of_vaults, 'regex', host_vault_name) }}"
    fail_msg: "Vault {{ host_vault_name }} was not found in the list."
```

and the 'list_of_vaults' is

```yaml
ansible_facts:
  list_of_vaults: |-
    - [3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy, rpi-tick1-keyvault]
    - [feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m, rpi-tick2-keyvault]
    - [6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa, rpi-tick3-keyvault]
```

But the results are

```
TASK [init : Does list_of_vaults contain the host_vault_name?] 

ok: [rpi-tick2 -> localhost({{ inventory_hostname }}.{{ network }})] => changed=false 
  msg: 'Vault rpi-tick2-keyvault found at index: 2'
```

So, the 'ansible.utils.index_of' function is indexing starting at one? Tick 1, 2 & 3 have indexes 1, 2 & 3 respectively. That just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: "*How to run a play that determines whether a specific hostname (such as `rpi-tick4`) is in the keyvault list?*"**

Just use `when` `in`.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    vaults_list:
      stdout: |
        ID                            NAME
        3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
        feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
        6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault
      stdout_lines:
        - ID                            NAME
        - 3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
        - feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
        - 6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault

    HOSTNAME: 'rpi-tick4'

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ vaults_list.stdout }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ vaults_list.stdout_lines | map('split') | to_yaml }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ HOSTNAME }}"
    when: HOSTNAME not in vaults_list.stdout

  - name: Does vaults_list contain value?
    assert:
      that: HOSTNAME in vaults_list.stdout
      success_msg: "Yes, it does."
      fail_msg: "No, it doesn't."
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    ID                            NAME
    3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
    feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
    6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault

TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    - [ID, NAME]
    - [3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy, rpi-tick1-keyvault]
    - [feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m, rpi-tick2-keyvault]
    - [6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa, rpi-tick3-keyvault]

TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: rpi-tick4

TASK [Does vaults_list contain value?] ***************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: HOSTNAME in vaults_list.stdout
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: No, it doesn't.
```

---

Or if interested in which "line" the value is

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    vaults_list:
      stdout: |
        ID                            NAME
        3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
        feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
        6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault
      stdout_lines:
        - ID                            NAME
        - 3rbnuw4hwdom7ml3ybzxsf32yy    rpi-tick1-keyvault
        - feo3jssa7f5z7mu33vdhnw4z5m    rpi-tick2-keyvault
        - 6isbi432wgixppnb4qcrdibkxa    rpi-tick3-keyvault

    HOSTNAME: 'rpi-tick2'

  tasks:

    # Create a list of lists from stdout_lines without header ([1:])

  - set_fact:
      LIST_OF_LISTS: "{{ vaults_list.stdout_lines[1:] | map('split') }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.index_of', LIST_OF_LISTS, 'regex', HOSTNAME) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '1'
```

for the second line, counted from zero.

For

```yaml
    HOSTNAME: 'rpi-tick4'
```

it would result into

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: []
```

since it is not contained.